# Optimizing calculation for Weighted Geometric Mean of a big set of data using GPU

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, gpu, geometric-mean

I need help with an optimization and performance problem related to the calculation of the Weighted Geometric Mean of some data.

I introduce the problem with a little sample.
I wrote the code to calculate the WGM for the simple example below.

```
% A matrix Example 3x3 matrix
% w column vector 3x1
% wgm row vector 1x3


A = rand(3);
w = [1,2,6]';
wgm = (prod(A.^w)).^(1/sum(w));
```

**Now for the general problem**:

Suppose I have a new **A matrix sized nxm**
and a W matrix composed of weight columns where weights values can go from 0 to k and I need all the columns permutations.

That is the **W matrix is sized as n x k^n**, since the nature of the weights and the weighted geometric computation this final matrix should be reduced **excluding columns that represent a multiplication by a scalar value** going from 0 to k of a permutation.

So if I have a column like [1, 1, 0] already that should exclude all t*[1,1,0] with t going from 0 to k.
Another example: [1 2 3] should exclude [2 4 6] or [3 6 9] and so on.

**Basic idea**: each generated column for the **W matrix could be normalized dividing each weight by k**, so if the new normalized column is redundant should not be added then converted back to an uint8 column to reduce memory consumption to 12.5%.

So considering a **real data example** suppose:

1. I have a static A matrix 32x30.
2. Weights values that go from 0 to 99.
3. I need a way to create the W Matrix sized 32x100^32 and to optimize it.
4. To calculate an optimized originally WGM 100^32x30 matrix where each row is the computation result from A matrix and corresponding W column.

So the problems to solve are:

- Creation of the optimized matrix of Weights both in size and performance.
- Calculation of the WGM Matrix.
- A way to allocate and partition those matrixes to avoid memory problems.
- Converting the Matlab code to GPU code for computation on a **Cuda Device (1080 GTX with 8 GB video memory)**.
- Storing the final matrices in an efficient way.

**Added information:**

The Weighted Geometric Means matrix data will be validated through a set of stricter rules, and so not compliant rows will be discarded, same for the final W matrix where the elimination will occur for corresponding columns.

**This could be evaluated earlier while creating the 2 matrices to find a solution that optimizes memory consumption while being maybe less efficient performance wise**.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question is how to write an optimized solution that takes into account the problems listed in the end with the first algoritm as a codebase with modifications needed to deal expecially with the memory, I've no Idea on how to start optimizing this apart what i listed, huge memory seems to be required to handle it.
Also converting to code for parallel computing is a problem too (since I never did anything like this) and I think the data must be prepared to work correctly for using it on the GPU.

Comment: You are just asking how to do everything, or for a tutorial, none of them an appropiate question in stackoverflow

Comment: I don't need the full solution to the problem, those are the problems I need to solve, If I get some help I can move forward, and so I'll eventually figure out other steps while I dig the problems further.
I detailed all the problems so I can get more precise replies avoiding people not to fully understand the problems I'm facing or having answers that will be good for a problem and at the same time bad for another.